# addEventListener on keyup javascript once

Tags: javascript, function, keydown

I want to run `countup();` and `random();` function after I hit enter on my keyboard. But I wanna make that it's only work for the first time.I mean when first time i hit enter, it will run that function. But if those function already run and I hit enter again, it'll never effect anything.

Here's my code :

```
addEventListener("keydown", function(e){
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        countup();
        random();
    }
});
```

Anyone can help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Idea is user a global variable, set it after firing event.

```
var is_fired = false;
addEventListener("keydown", function(e){
    if (e.keyCode === 13 && is_fired == false) {
        countup();
        random();
        is_fired = true
    }
});
```

Answer (score 13):

Do something like this

```
// Create a named function as your event handler
var myFunction = function (e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 13) {
    // Do your stuff here
    countup();
    random();

    // Remove event listener so that next time it is not triggered
    removeEventListener("keydown", myFunction);
  }
};

// Bind "keydown" event
addEventListener("keydown", myFunction);
```

Comment: Definitely the better approach.

Comment: Great solution.

Answer (score 5):

You can make click event listener work only once after trigger it.you just need to add another argument to `addEventListener()` which is `{once:true}`and it will work as expected:

```
addEventListener("keydown", function(e){
      if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        countup();
        random();
      }
},{once: true});
```

Check my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43393544/disable-click-event-listener-of-square-temporally-color-picker-game) it's similar to your case.

Also you can just use `removeEventListener()`method but you should defined your Anonymous function before as external function like `myKeyPressed()` and then inside if condition remove event Listener from your element:

```
element.removeEventListener("keydown", myKeyPressed);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var is_clicked = false;
addEventListener("keydown", function(e){
      if (e.keyCode === 13 && !is_clicked) {
        countup();
        random();
        is_clicked = true;
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a removeEventListener function in javascript but it's tricky to implement that inside the function you are calling on addEventListener.
Try this, it worked in jsfiddle.

```
addEventListener("keydown", function(e){
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        alert("i did it");
        this.removeEventListener('keydown',arguments.callee,false);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a variable to check the status of your keydown.
The first time you use it, set it up to true. So you will only have this function triggered once.

Comment: This should be a comment

Answer (score 0):

```
 var n = document.getElementById("txtInput"),
          r = document.getElementById("result"),
          loadFlag = true;

      n.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
       if (e.keyCode === 13 && loadFlag ) {
                countup(r);   
        random(r);
        loadFlag = false;
        }
      }, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

To add keydown to an element in your HTML code.

```
element.addEventListener("keydown", event => {
//check if event is cancelable because not all event can be cancelled
if(event.cancelable)
   { 
       //this prevent element from executing the default event when user click
       event.preventDefault()
       if(event.keycode === 13){ //write your statement here }
   }
}
```

for more https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_preventdefault.asp